# Find the image of a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hey I just wanted to know if I'm doing what the problem is asking me to do correctly. I'm new to set theory, so I apologize in advance for not wording everything correctly.

Let $A=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, $B=\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$. Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be defined by

$f(1)=2$, $f(2)=3$, $f(3)=3$, $f(4)=6$, $f(5)=7$ .

The question asks to find the image of $f : \{2, 3, 6, 7\}$

My answer is $im(f) = \{3\}$

My reasoning is that $f : \{2, 3, 6, 7\}$ are $x$ values that I'm mapping onto $B$, $2$ and $3$ being the only ones that have a corresponding $y$ in $B$. And usually the $x$ values I'm using are included in a subset of $A$, but in this case $\{2, 3, 6, 7\}$ are not a subset of $A$.

Comment: The image is $\{2,3,6,7\}$.

Comment: Is it my lack of understanding of the subject or is Lord Shark's answer and Kumar's answer contradicting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct. Since $f$ is not defined for $6$ or $7$, the $image(f)=\{3\}$